# Ubuntu can't detect wifi, even after reinstalling the driver (BCM43142)

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 14.10, broadcom

Recently after fiddling a bit with routers in my apartment I discovered that ubuntu can't detect my own home network anymore. It had no problems doing it for last 6 months.

What I already did:

- `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
- `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Weird events before that happened include:

- retrying connection to my home wifi even after trying to connect to other one (it stopped after reboot),
- long connect-in-progress times,
- denying to connect to perfectly good network, even though my other pc did it with no problem.

If someone could suggest me what can I do now I would be very grateful.

@edit:
Done what comments said :).
http://pastebin.com/KwUBsvK0

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: Done that, logs in edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repaired it setting my WiFi fixed on channel 7, now ubuntu detects it with ease again. It Was auto-set on channel 11. I'm curious why BCM can't detect it on channels higher than 10.